# Cant Click after update to 12.10

Tags: mouse

Just updated from 12.04 to the newest 12.10 and now I can't click things correctly.

Things I can click on are
top black bar
cons left side of the screen 
things on my desktop such as short cuts and folders

However if I open a folder for instance I can not click anything in it, instead each time I click the mouse pointer turns into a grab fist icon, I cant click things in programs like Firefox aswell.

I found that I can click anything if I hold ctrl first before clicking.

please help return my mouse to normal!.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem with my mouse too.
I have bluetooth mouse (this may not be the case), and some of my left clicks are captured, and some of them are unrecognized.
I have to press the left-click button longer than before.

In the same time, right-click and my tuchpad (left and right) buttons work well.